# <f:propertyActionListener> tag not found

Tags: eclipse, jsf, datatable, icefaces, commandlink

I cant seem to get  to work.  I am using icefaces and a very simple  with two columns.  One with actions such as remove and the other with a string (representing a regular expression).  In order for the remove action to remove the right row, I am trying to link it to the actual element with an :

```
<html xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:m="http://www.mitre.org/asias/jsf">
  <ui:composition> 
    <ice:dataTable binding="#{binding}" 
      value="#{binding.editableRows}"
      var="item">
      <ice:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <ice:commandLink styleClass="linkBlue"
            action="#{binding.addEditableRow}">
            <ice:outputText value="Add" />
          </ice:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:commandLink styleClass="linkBlue"
          action="#{binding.removeEditableRow}">
          <f:propertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{binding.actionRow}" />
          <ice:outputText value="Remove" />
        </ice:commandLink>
      </ice:column>
      <ice:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <ice:outputText value="Regular Expression" />
        </f:facet>
        <ice:inputText value="#{item.object}" size="100" />
      </ice:column>
    </ice:dataTable>
  </ui:composition> 
</html>
```

Everything I have found on this says that I need JSF 1.2.  I am using JSF 1.2.  Here is the apache Ivy config file I am using to manage my dependencies:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

 <info organisation="org.mitre.asias" module="testwebproject" />

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="default->default">
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="needed for deployment" extends="runtime,master" />
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="only this artifact" />
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="libraries only needed at runtime" extends="compile" />
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="provided by container, not needed for deployment" />
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="needed for testing" />
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="needed for compilation" />
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="the source artifact, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="the javadoc artifact, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
        <conf name="ide" visibility="public" description="all libraries, sources, and javadoc needed for ide" extends="master,compile,provided,test,sources,javadoc" />
    </configurations>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.4" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.1" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />

        <dependency org="javax.el" name="el-api" rev="2.1.2-b05" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)" />
        <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="servlet-api" rev="2.5" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)" />
        <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="jsp-api" rev="2.0" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)" />
        <dependency org="org.icefaces" name="icefaces" rev="1.8.2" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="org.icefaces" name="icefaces-comps" rev="1.8.2" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="org.icefaces" name="icefaces-facelets" rev="1.8.2" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="javax.faces" name="jsf-api" rev="1.2_13" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="javax.faces" name="jsf-impl" rev="1.2_13" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
        <dependency org="com.sun.facelets" name="jsf-facelets" rev="1.1.14" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />

        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.1" conf="test->default" />

        <exclude module="servlet-api" conf="default" />
        <exclude module="el-api" conf="default" />
        <exclude module="jsp-api" conf="default" />
 </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I am using eclipse with IvyDE to manage that library and a Tomcat server instance running with "Use workspace metadata" selected.  Is there some eclipse or tomcat thing that might be injecting the wrong version of JSF?  When I look at the jsf-impl jar that is included by Ivy, I do see that there are com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SetPropertyActionListenerImpl and SetPropertyActionListenerTag in that jar.  It is my understanding that those should be all that is needed.  Any Ideas?  Am I missing something, or just plain going crazy?

---

**EDIT:**

Now I'm getting really frustrated.  Per the suggestion from BalusC I updated my faces-config.xml to use the 1.2 schema definition instead of the 1.1 dtd.  This did not help.  So I search around for more information.  I find another stackoverflow article pertaining to ([this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306309/jsf-core-issue-javax-servlet-servletexception)), however there was no resolution other than getting a new version of jsf-facelets.jar (of which the new/old version is not listed).  I am using the latest version available on repo1.maven.org/maven2 ([1.1.14](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/facelets/jsf-facelets/1.1.14/)).  So no go on that front.  My new questions are, why would facelets have anything to do with this?  Its a part of the JSF core is it not?  I notice that in my *jsf-impl-1.2_13.jar::META-INF/jsf_core.tld*, there is a tag for setPropertyActionListener:

```
<tag>
    ...
    <name>setPropertyActionListener</name>
    <tag-class>com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SetPropertyActionListenerTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    ...
</tag>
```

On top of that, this can be found in my *jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar::com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/core/CoreLibrary.java*:

```
...
this.addTagHandler("setPropertyActionListener", SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.class);
...
```

It looks like my included libraries should be sufficient.  Any idea what is going on here?  Do I need to go back and get a degree in JSF to be able to write a simple facelet?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the root declaration of your `faces-config.xml` is declared as per JSF 1.2 specification.

```
<faces-config version="1.2" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">
```

Further, the `binding="#{binding}"` in your datatable really doesn't look right since `#{binding}` seems to be a managed bean.

Comment: I did not know this about faces-config having version="1.2".  I will have to wait until tomorrow to test this as I am not in front of the code at the moment.  As for the binding="#{binding}, I do that because this facelet is intended to be included in another page with a <m:editableTable binding="#{mybean.editableTable}"> tag so the binding variable in this code refers to the one defined in that tag.  Thank you for your response and I will be sure to update this as the answer if it works.

Comment: Also the `xsi:schemaLocation` is different. As for the binding, it should refer an `UIComponent` not a managed bean. Is it really an `UIComponent`?

Comment: Thanks again, I didnt notice the schemaLocation difference. And, yes, it is an extension of HtmlDataTable so as to work as a binding for my ice:dataTable.

Answer (score 1):

I really hate to answer my own question, especially since it was such a simple mistake, but sometimes we just have to fess up and accept the public humiliation.  Anyway, long story short, its:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{binding.actionRow}" />
```

not

```
<f:propertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{binding.actionRow}" />
```

Hopefully, this will help someone else in the future...